# Android user login error once application closes

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using SharedPreferences for saving credentials which works fine but when the application is killed the user is asked to login again.

When the credentials are saved the user should not be asked to login if the application is killed. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
     public static final String PREFS_NAME = "myFile";
     private String user; 
     private String userName; 

     @Override 
     public void onRestart(){
           super.onRestart();
           userName = null;
           user=null;

           //Retrieve the preferences.
           SharedPreferences credentials = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE); 

           user = credentials.getString(userName, null);
           //Check for stored preferences.  
           if (user!=null) {
              Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
              startActivity(j);
              finish(); 

           } 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setting default screen to login.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_login_new);

        //Initializing the fields from XML layout.

        final Button login_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

        //Retrieve the preferences.
        SharedPreferences credentials = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = credentials.edit(); 
        userName = null;
        user=null;


        //retrieve the stored values.
        user = credentials.getString(userName, null);
        //Check for stored preferences. 
        if (user!=null){
            Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            j.putExtra("user_name", user);
            startActivity(j);
            finish(); 
        }    

        //Listener for the login button.
            login_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    // Verify the username and password.
                    if ( 
                            (username_login.getText().toString()).equals("test")&&(password_login.getText().toString()).equals("test")){
                        //Store the credentials in sharedPreferences.
                        user=username_login.getText().toString();
                        editor.putString(userName, username_login.getText().toString()).commit();

                            j.putExtra("user_name", user);
                        startActivity(j);
                        finish(); 
                        }
                    else{
                        Display_error_msg();
                        }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Is MyActivity.PREFS_NAME the same as FileActivity.PREFS_NAME? You use a different SharedPreferences name in onRestart() and onCreate().

Also, why are you trying to store userName in SharedPreferences under a null key value?

Comment: yes, it's the same file, I edited it now, sorry for the confusion. I don't understand you by saying that I am using different sharedpreferences. The same file (PREFS_NAME = "myFile") is accessed so it shouldn't be a problem. is it? What I don't understand is why the file is lost when I or the system kills the app? When I press the back button the app switch to background, if I open the app after 10 mins I don't need to log in but when the system kills the app I am asked to enter the credentials again. I don't know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You still haven't addressed why you're trying to save information using a null key value. 
At no point in the code you have provided do you set userName to anything but null.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing has some errors, you have not commited shared preferences values and there is no proper tags for store and retrive. just look at this code

```
if ((username_login.getText().toString()).equals("test")&&(password_login.getText().toString()).equals("test")){
    //Store the credentials in sharedPreferences.
    user=username_login.getText().toString();
    editor.putString("UserName", username_login.getText().toString()).commit();

    editor.commit();  //// changes will be effect after commit only

    j.putExtra("user_name", user);
    startActivity(j);
    finish(); 
} else {
    Display_error_msg();
}
```

and in another activity

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
     public static final String PREFS_NAME = "myFile";
     private String user; 
     private String userName; 

     @Override 
     public void onRestart(){
         super.onRestart();
         userName = "UserName";
         user=null;

         //Retrieve the preferences.
         SharedPreferences credentials = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE); 

         user = credentials.getString(userName, null);
         //Check for stored preferences. 
         if (user!=null){
             Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
             startActivity(j);
             finish(); 
         } 
 }
```

Comment: I tried that but it's not working. the problem is with killing the app. >when it's killed then all the data is lost. > I want the application to save the data when it's killed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onResume()` instead of `onRestart()` to checking user login.

These are activity's life cycles, Not application's. ie, onRestart() doesn't mean app restart.